# Netbeans - Cannot find include file : QtGui

Tags: qt, netbeans

I am trying to work with Netbeans ans Qt (on Windows) and I am having trouble getting set up.

I am getting a message that it can't find an included file: QtGui/QApplication.

I think that I must have a path wrong somewhere.  Under Tools -> Options QMake Command I have 
C:\Qt\2010.02.1\qt\bin\qmake.exe

In Windows, I have the PATH set to C:\Qt\2010.02.1\qt\bin

Any ideas?

Comment: I have read the article on using Qt with Netbeans.  My setup looks like what they suggest, but still no luck.